# PHP compare triggered from JQuery AJAX not returning value

Tags: php

I am using `jQuery` to invoke a `PHP` script to update a `MYSQL` db, but first do a logical test based on the value. This issue I am finding it if I build my query this way, i got error `Query was empty`.

Logically I tried to resolve the test to no avail. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
$type= trim($_POST['type']);
if( $type == "wanted" ) {
   $qUpdate = "UPDATE Post...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be that my compare was not comparing apples to apples:

`if ($type == mysql_real_escape_string("wanted") )`

Answer (score 0):

POST may not get by normal ajax

```
$type= trim($_REQUEST['type']);
if( $type == "wanted" ) {
   $qUpdate = "UPDATE Post...";
   // Query must be correct in syntax ,I think its intentional for demo purpose
   if(mysql_query($qUpdate)) {
     echo "success";
   }
   else {
     echo "fail";
   }
}
```

This  "success" and "fail" texts will get as response on your ajax

Comment: The other piece of the puzzle, if I remove the IF statement, the query posts successfully.

Answer (score 0):

try $_GET['type'], the php-script is called from a url, not from a form. So it's a $_GET parameter, not $_POST

Comment: I forgot to mention I invoked this from this from an AJAX statement where I write: 

type: "POST",

Answer (score 0):

You should check your query and sure it is all correct and the variables are stripped, try this

```
$type = mysql_escape_real_string($_POST['type']);
$sql = "UPDATE table....."
//query the code and ensure if there's an error kill the script
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Let me know how you get on!:)